# Firebase from Flask deployment server

Tags: apache, flask, google-cloud-firestore, mod-wsgi, wsgi

in development mode with Flask, I am successfully able to read and write data to Firestore using the firebase admin module. However, once I deploy the app on Apache 2 using mod_wsgi, everything works fine (firebase app initialization doesn't throw any error) until I start getting a document, where the code gets stuck and the page loads forever.

**Flask function where the problem occurs in __init__.py:**

```py
@app.route('/users/<user>')
def login(user=None):
    if not user:
        abort(404)

    userRef = db.collection('users').document(user)
    print("1") # This runs.
    userDoc = userRef.get() # The code gets stuck here. No error message is ever returned or stored in the error log.
    print("2") # This never runs.
```

**flaskapp.wsgi**

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.8

import sys
import os
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
os.chdir("/var/www/html/example.com/FlaskApp/")
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/example.com/FlaskApp/")
from __init__ import app as application
```

**example.com.conf**

```php
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py38.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/usr/local"

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin username@example.com
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html

  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/example.com/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
  <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/FlaskApp/>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  Alias /static /var/www/html/example.com/FlaskApp/static
  <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/FlaskApp/static/>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/example.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Do you know how to make Firebase `get()` works in a deployed Flask app? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is your app deployed? It looks that it might be missing service account auth credentials.

Comment: The app is deployed on an Apache server. It seems to find the Firebase credentials as it is able to run db = firestore.client() without returning any error.

Comment: THis sounds like a Compute Engine instance, check its [access scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam), and enable Datastore access if it is not already, also check its service account roles.

Comment: Hi @TomLamensia, I'm facing the same problem. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @sambam In the end, I ran the Flask application on port 3000 using Gunicorn on a Linux service. Then on my Apache conf file, I added a proxy from specific endpoints to port 3000. That way I'm able to choose exactly which endpoints should be static for Apache and which endpoints should call the Flask application.

Comment: That gives me great headstart thanks a lot @TomLamensia!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like WSGI needs to be forced to use the main Python interpreter. Therefore, you'll need to add `application-group=%{GLOBAL}` to the end of your ``WSGIScriptAlias line on `example.com.conf`, so that the line now reads:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/example.com/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

After that, restart Apache with the terminal command `systemctl restart apache` and your problem should be solved.